# LG G5 stuck with screen showing a picture as if the battery is not attached

Tags: battery, lg-g5

My LG G5 is stuck with a screen showing a picture as if the battery is not attached. I don't know what is the reason.

[image]

If I remove the battery for a while and reattach it, it works.

I tried to search about it online, but could not find any information.

What does this mean and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried Google translate for understanding the Korean symbols?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=전원을+켜려면+모델에+맞는+정상+모듈을+장착해+주세요 brushing and cleaning contacts of module might help https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3425279&page=2